# Show buttons again with search cross

Tags: javascript

Based on this search engine: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_filters_anything

Changing the code: type="text" to type="search" it show a cross (X) on the right side

If you try to type anything and then you click on the X, the text is deleted... however the buttons are not shown until you press ENTER.

How to show the buttons after clicking the X?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the event listener from `"keyup"` to `"input"`, so that when an input occurs, your jQuery code will be triggered. Currently, your code is listening for keyup events, and so it won't call your event's callback until you enter text into your search input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Filter Anything</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV":</p>
<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myDIV">
  <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
  <div>I am a div element inside div.</div>
  <button>I am a button</button>
  <button>Another button</button>
  <p>Another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```